# How to get the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS value using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-calc-found-rows

I'm currently scratching my head at how to implement `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with prepared statements.

I'm writing a pagination class and obviously i want to add LIMIT to the query but also find what the total number of rows would be.

Here's an example from the class in question.

```
$query = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title,location,salary,employer from jobs where region=38 limit 0,3";

if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute()or die($connection->error); //execute query
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$location,$salary,$employer,$image);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $jobs[$x]['id']=$id;
        $jobs[$x]['title']=$title;
        $jobs[$x]['location']=$location;
        $jobs[$x]['salary']=$salary;
        $jobs[$x]['employer']=$employer;
        $jobs[$x]['image']=$image;
        $x++;
    }
    $stmt->close();//close statement
}
```

I'm a bit stumped as to how to get the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` actual value? I had thought adding in something like:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$count=$stmt->num_rows;
```

But that only gives a number based on the LIMIT, so in the above example its 3 rather than the full 6 that it should be.

Comment: Ok, i have since found out i need to use SELECT FOUND_ROWS() but im still unsure how to implement this? Do i need to run it like a completely new query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, i will detail my answer below for anyone whos interested in future.

**Original Code**

```
$query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title,location,salary,employer from jobs where region=38 limit 0,3";

if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute()or die($connection->error); //execute query
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$location,$salary,$employer,$image);
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $jobs[$x]['id']=$id;
            $jobs[$x]['title']=$title;
            $jobs[$x]['location']=$location;
            $jobs[$x]['salary']=$salary;
            $jobs[$x]['employer']=$employer;
            $jobs[$x]['image']=$image;
            $x++;
        }
        $stmt->close();//close statement
    }
```

**Updated Code**

```
$query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title,location,salary,employer from jobs where region=38 limit 0,3";

if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute()or die($connection->error); //execute query
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$location,$salary,$employer,$image);
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $jobs[$x]['id']=$id;
            $jobs[$x]['title']=$title;
            $jobs[$x]['location']=$location;
            $jobs[$x]['salary']=$salary;
            $jobs[$x]['employer']=$employer;
            $jobs[$x]['image']=$image;
            $x++;
        }
            //get total number of rows.
            $query="SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($num);
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                $count=$num;
            }

        $stmt->close();//close statement
    }
```

Probably could do it better another way but couldn't seem to find any good examples anywhere online and this works!

Comment: You don't need to use the "while" as it's just returning a single row

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` you need to run query `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` in MySQL. To do that you don't need prepared statement. You can just use `query()` method.

```
$connection->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetch_row()[0];
```

If you are using mysqlnd, which you should be using if you are on one of the supported PHP versions, you can make your code much simpler.

```
// Enable error reporting instead of using or die($connection->error)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title,location,salary,employer 
    FROM jobs 
    WHERE region=38 
    LIMIT 0,3";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$jobs = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// There is no need for prepared statement when using FOUND_ROWS()
$connection->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetch_row()[0];
```

As you can see, it is much cleaner to use `fetch_all()` rather than `while` loop.

[**Warning**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

> The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS()
>   function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a
>   future MySQL version. As a replacement, considering executing your
>   query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without
>   LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows. For example,
>   instead of these queries:
>
> ```
> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
> ```
>
> Use these queries instead:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
> SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE id > 100;
> ```