# Find last loop of while($stmt->fetch())

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, prepared-statement

Is it possible to find when is the last loop of :

```
$stmt = $connection->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT `ProductId` FROM Products"))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($product_id);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
       if ($lastloop)
       {
          echo 'The last id is -> ';
       }

       echo $product_id.'<br />';
    }
}
```

I want to output something like :

1
2
...
9
The last id is -> 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use [**`$stmt->num_rows`**^](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php), but **ONLY if you `$stmt->store_result()` the result set** and keep counting the active row offset. *Storing the results is not viable for large sets.*
2. Use **`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ProductId FROM Products;`** like in [this **answer** here^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049725/mysqli-prepared-statements-sql-calc-found-rows). And then use `FOUND_ROWS()` to know the row number **WITHOUT storing the result set** initially. *Requires one extra query... which is a small price to pay.*

*That's all you've got as viable and easy solutions.*

Comment: About solotuion 1. If i got a limit 100 in my query, will be considered as a large set?

Comment: @zPuls3 If you have `TEXT/BLOB` columns with KBs/MBs of data and you do `SELECT *`... it is. **If you only `SELECT` specific small columns, like here... it's not.**

Comment: @zPuls3 *Just an extra comment.* If you `SELECT` specific small columns within reasonable bounds... it's MUCH better to store always as this limits round trips to server. Otherwise, for each `fetch`... a new communication with the server is necessary. Which is good for large sets but not that good for smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep count and compare to the number of rows

```
$stmt->store_result();
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$count = 1;
while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    if( $count == $rows ) {
        echo 'The last id is -> ';
    }
    $count ++;
    echo $product_id . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: this is not working. EDIT it does need an $stmt->store_result();

Comment: edited. Sorry I'm more familiar with PDO that does it slightly differently